# how do i connect my mongodb to my laptop?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I made a mongodb account , and tried connecting it with my laptop. it has been giving me this error

here is my mongoose connection`

```
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.atfhj.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?authSource=yourDB&w=1',
    {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("database connected");
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
app.use(bodyParser)
```

here is the error

```
server started on port 5000
MongoError: Authentication failed.
at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\JUWONCALEB.DESKTOP-CMA289U\Desktop\UDEMY\ECOMMERCE\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268:20)
at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
at processIncomingData (C:\Users\JUWONCALEB.DESKTOP-CMA289U\Desktop\UDEMY\ECOMMERCE\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\JUWONCALEB.DESKTOP-CMA289U\Desktop\UDEMY\ECOMMERCE\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
}
```

Comment: `MONGO_DB_USER` and/or `MONGO_DB_PASSWORD` are probably wrong, since authentication failed

Comment: Oh, I see the problem ... you're using `'` instead of `\`` in the connection url - should be `\`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.atfhj.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?authSource=yourDB&w=1\`` if you want to use `${....}`

Comment: i changed it and still got the same error

Comment: try `console.log(\`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.atfhj.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?authSource=yourDB&w=1\`)` - does it look right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Backticks when interpolating strings.

```
mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.atfhj.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?authSource=yourDB&w=1`,
    {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("database connected");
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
app.use(bodyParser)
```

Comment: Did you save your `MONGO_DB_USER`, `MONGO_DB_PASSWORD` and `MONGO_DB_DATABASE` as Environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using strings here `''` and not back tics ``` `` ```. So that was probably the reason why you were getting that error.
Another probability is that you maybe have configured your `env` in a wrong way. Check if you env is working by using console logging it.

Finally, I suggest you put the whole mongoDB Connection as an `env` and then just use the env without having to worry about strings.
For example:

inside your .env file:

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION=mongodb+srv://the-user:user-password@cluster0.atfhj.mongodb.net/your-database?authSource=yourDB&w=1
```

then just do this

```
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION,
    {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("database connected");
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
app.use(bodyParser)
```